# React Native Native Java/Android Module - not showing toast message

Tags: android, react-native, native-module

I'm using the [example found here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android) & currently facing issue with the toast not showing at all... I just have the initial 'Welcome to React Native!' screen in the emulator. My app structure is as follows:

```
testApp
  android
    app
      src
        main
          java
            com
              testApp
                CustomToastPackage.java
                MainActivity.java
                MainApplication.java
                ToastModule.java              
          res
          assets
            index.android.bundle
          AndroidManifest.xml
  ios
  node_modules
  app.json
  App.js
  index.js
  package.json
  ToastExample.js
  yarn.lock
```

My index.js

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

import {NativeModules} from 'react-native'; //Added this

module.exports = NativeModules.testApp; //Added this

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

My App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';

import ToastExample from './ToastExample'; //Added this

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' + 'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android:
    'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native!</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>To get started, edit App.js</Text>
    <Text style={styles.instructions}>{instructions}</Text>
  </View>
);
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
fontSize: 20,
textAlign: 'center',
margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
textAlign: 'center',
color: '#333333',
marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
```

As you can see from the file structure I created an additional file named ToastExample.js that contains following based upon [the answer found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51800550/react-native-native-android-module-toast-example/51803740)

```
import {NativeModules} from 'react-native';
module.exports = NativeModules.ToastExample;
```

Package name is simply

```
com.testapp
```

I can't figure out why the toast never shows? I know react comes with toast support but looking to build upon an initial example to include more advanced Java/Android code...

Comment: I'm kind of confused. I can't seem to find where you're actually calling ToastExample inside the render function of your `App.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you didn't add `ToastExample` in index.js you need to add this into rendering method in index.js like below.

```
return(
    <ToastExample/>
)
```

---

In addition to that, you are going to create an android native module which can be used only for android. 
But According to my point of view, you can use toast messages module which can be used in both Android and Ios. Otherwise, you need to create ios base native module for creating toast for ios. If u don't want to ios base implementation, it's ok to use this native module. But you block your Ios deployment by it.

I would like to suggest this https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-easy-toast#readme
easy-toast for u. It will work on both Android and IOS devices. You can customize it like android native toast as well. It is easy to implement in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Ariel & @Lucefer for feedback, I made the update you suggested but ran into another error. Posting this answer to save anyone potential headache caused by using Android Studio as IDE with React Native. Turns out the MainApplication.java file had 2 items (import of CustomToastPackage & ReactPackage) greyed out & could never figure out why? See the screenshot below

[image]

I created a separate application (react-native init newapp) & used a simple text editor (Atom or gedit will do instead of Android Studio) to make the changes & the example runs just fine now.

Comment: duplicates will normally be the result of running the link command more than once. I'd recommend checking your other gradle files for potential duplicates as well. Great job on finding a solution!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<Root>
<View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native!</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>To get started, edit App.js</Text>
    <Text style={styles.instructions}>{instructions}</Text>
  </View>
</Root>
```

just import Root to react native